# What DLC items are included in the Gears of War 3 Season Pass?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

A friend and I were looking to get back to Gears of War 3 again and see what was new in terms of DLC. I went a-lookin' and... well, there's definitely plenty to sort through.

As I was looking through the list, I came across a "Season Pass" DLC. It's quite expensive compared to the rest, however it claims to offer 33% off from buying its contents normally.

Can't say I'd argue with 33% off. Unfortunately, the listing for this DLC doesn't list what comes with it:

> The Season Pass serves as your pre-order (at a 33% discount!) of four downloadable content packages that you will receive every quarter, starting in November.

I realize that it can't exactly name what isn't out yet, but what of the ones that have been released? Following the every quarter logic, two of them have become available and one should be on the way. There are definitely more than two listings available for Gears of War 3...

**Which of the DLC packs available for Gears of War 3 are provided when the Season Pass is purchased?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *first* Gears of War 3 Season Pass grants access to:

- [**Horde Command Pack**](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Horde-Command-Pack/c64185a3-da78-48a6-b7ec-74fa3c2ef889)
- [**RAAM's Shadow: Pack 2**](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/RAAMs-Shadow-Pack-2/bdb2cae2-077c-47f5-ae95-ef60d0ede368)
- [**Fenix Rising Map Pack**](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Fenix-Rising-Map-Pack/bd626bbb-9d44-4561-ae68-0ee97e2377e9)
- [**Forces of Nature Map Pack**](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Forces-of-Nature-Map-Pack/268cd22d-f9d1-4833-ba47-99e50722d922)

and **the [Season Pass exclusive](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Gears-of-War-3-Season-Pass/b38b82ce-1dc6-4028-a69b-514babca6db0) [Liquid Metal Skins](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mbPZtwxzfo&hd=1)**.

I have it and can confirm.

I said *first* because there's been talk of more season passes to come although I'm not sure whether it's been confirmed or not.

Comment: So is there other DLC available not included in the season pass? I know the skins aren't (some of the skins are actually surprisingly cool).

Comment: The pass also includes the [pass-exclusive](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Gears-of-War-3-Season-Pass/b38b82ce-1dc6-4028-a69b-514babca6db0) [liquid metal skins](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mbPZtwxzfo&hd=1).